# Use ajax to post back to same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I would like to post the result of an ajax request back to the same page that it was requested from. Here are the interacting parts:

**AJAX in Jquery**

```
var ids = 1

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#showbtn').on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:3000/teamplayers.json",
        data: {'resolution':ids}, 
        type:"post",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: true,
        success:function(){ 
            $('#test3').val(1);
            alert("test 3"); 
            },
        error: function(error) {
                   alert("Failed " + console.log(error) + " " + error)
                   }           
        });
    });
});
```

This is supposed to set a variable here:
**Teamplayer Controller**

```
# GET /teamplayers
# GET /teamplayers.json
def index
  @teamplayers = Teamplayer.all
  @fteams = Fteam.all
  @teamplayer2 = 1
  tid = params[:resolution] <-It should set here per the data section above
  @ids = tid
end
```

unfortunately it calls this section of the same controller

```
 # POST /teamplayers
 # POST /teamplayers.json
 def create
   @teamplayer = Teamplayer.new(teamplayer_params)

   respond_to do |format|
     if @teamplayer.save
       format.html { redirect_to @teamplayer, notice: 'Teamplayer was successfully created.' }
       format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @teamplayer }
    else
       format.html { render action: 'new' }
       format.json { render json: @teamplayer.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

So what do I do to make it post to the same page.

Answer (score 0):

You are `POST`ing the ajax, which means the `create` action will be hit, not the `index` action. You should be able to see this in your server log output when you hit the page.

If you want to hit the `index` action, you need to do an `GET` ajax request with the resolution data set so you can get the data you want.

Additionally, you probably maybe don't want to cache this ajax request if it is actually dynamic data, but it is up to you.

---

Edit from comments:

You need to add your parameter as a query string for a `GET`, not as generic "data".

Try something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:3000/teamplayers.json?resolution="+ids,
    type:"GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success:function(){ 
        $('#test3').val(1);
        alert("test 3"); 
        },
    error: function(error) {
               alert("Failed " + console.log(error) + " " + error)
               }           
    });
});
```

---

Another edit from comments:

```
# GET /teamplayers
# GET /teamplayers.json
def index
  @teamplayers = Teamplayer.all
  @fteams = Fteam.all
  @teamplayer2 = 1
  tid = params.fetch(:resolution) { 0 } # make sure we got something
  @ids = tid.to_i                       # coerce string param to integer
end
```

Comment: but when i do the get, it calls the page with the data at the end of the page. I want this: http://localhost:3000/teamplayers/ instead of this: http://localhost:3000/teamplayers/1

Comment: @user3240928 updated answer to reflect this, but you need to pass `resolution` as a query string argument.

Comment: ok now i know that it is passing the value but how pass the value as an integer

Comment: @user3240928 updated my answer again. Use `to_i` on the value to coerce a string to an int. But make sure you don't have a `nil`!